# How to get jmeter raw results for cancelled workflow in github actions

Tags: jmeter

I have configured Jmeter load tests with GitHub actions workflow. Some times we need to cancel/stop the workflow due to errors. I would like to collect the Jmeter raw results. I added below step to get raw results. But after downloading the file jtl results file is empty. How can I get raw results even though of the workflow stopped/cancelled?

```
  - name: Upload JMeter Raw Results
    if: always()
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
          name: JmeterResults
          path: '**.jtl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't write metrics into [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in the realtime to avoid high disk IO and [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), it keeps them in memory first and then stores to disk in batches.

It might be the case you're cancelling the workflow when the first chunk has not been written yet and hence you get an empty .jtl results file.

If you want to amend this behaviour you can set `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush` property to `true`

By the way I don't recall `if: always()` condition, when I touched Github Actions last time I used something like `if: ${{ always() }}` however it could change since then.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri! As usual, the most valuable and the fastest answer from you in #jmeter thread.